# Calling windows functions from machine code

Tags: c++, windows, function, 64-bit, portable-executable

Here is the walkthrough I'm using:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKwgd.jpg

From what I'm seeing is that to call a windows function, you put the arguments in specific registers.  But where is it listed what registers to use and what order?

Look at the code section of that image, it just seems to use r8d, r9, edx and ecx?  Does that mean it uses edx, ecx, r8d, r9d, r10d, etc?  What happens when you run out of registers for a function with many parameters?

Also why does it have to subtract from the stack? And why 0x28?

Comment: Most normal Windows (aka Win32) functions use stack for arguments. Consider editing your post to show text sample of function you trying to call along with code you are using... Or you are using "windows" as "any function that happen to be run on Windows machine"?

Comment: I'm just looking at the code section of the walkthrough I linked.  It uses registers to call both functions but I don't know why... (yes just win32 functions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Windows Registry Functions in Assembly Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269131/using-windows-registry-functions-in-assembly-language)

Comment: I see - you are asking about x64 calling convention, different from x86... Covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269131/using-windows-registry-functions-in-assembly-language - see linked MSDN article.

Comment: If you run out of registers, the rest should be passed onto the stack. The calling convention is documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b372w95.aspx

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys!  Any idea why there's a subtract op before calling those functions?